# Remove Line from file using preg_replace

Tags: php

I want remove this line from my config file

```
line :define('APP_MAIL_FROM_EMAIL_NAME','example');
```

Here is my code

```
<?php
$configFileContents = file_get_contents('config.php');
if (!empty($configFileContents)) {

            if (strstr($configFileContents, 'define(\'APP_MAIL_FROM_EMAIL_NAME\',')) {
            $configFileContents = preg_replace('/define\(\'APP_MAIL_FROM_EMAIL_NAME.*\R/', '', $configFileContents);
            }
            file_put_contents("config.php", $configFileContents);
        }   
?>
```

This code working fine but if that line like this

```
line :define('APP_MAIL_FROM_EMAIL_NAME' ,'example');
```

if space present between `APP_MAIL_FROM_EMAIL_NAME' ,` and comma its not working 
what is the problem any changes needed what??

Comment: remove `\R` from the regex, or make it optional

Comment: even if i removed \R not working . and also its removing only content but not removing entire content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it will include all space between your character

```
preg_replace('/define\(\'APP_MAIL_FROM_EMAIL_NAME.s+*\R/', '', $configFileContents);
```